# checking query arguments for loopback ACLs to allow `find`ing the user's data only

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have two loopback services running independently in docker containers and they talk to each other.

One handles `Users` and the other handles some `UserData` associated with a User. They are connected via a remote connector on both servers that point to the other server.

When the current `User` updates their details on server A it needs to update some UserData on server B. Auth is done using JWT tokens, and I managed to get server A to forward the token it was given to server B.

The problem I am having is that `user.data()` on server A gets passed to the remote connector and turned into a query like `/api/UserData/find?filter[where][userId]=2` on server B, but the ACLs on server B do not allow queries on `find` because then you could get everyone's data by just changing the where clause.

Is there a way to create a dynamic Role that lets a user filter by their own data? (ie, can I check the query params in the Role resolver somehow?)

Comment: You should be able to use a [dynamic role and a custom resolver function](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Dynamicroles) to do this. The resolver gets a `context` object, but I'm not sure what's on it... you could check to see if there is a `req` object (the HTTP request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this was to create a role that checks the arguments in the `context.remotingContext.req` and verifies that the where for the current user is included in the arguments.